# Two versions of the Chebyshev polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials, partial-differential-equations

I found that there two versions of the Chebyshev polynomial, that is,

(Version 1)
$$H_k(t):=\frac{1}{2}\left(t+i\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)^k+\frac{1}{2}\left(t-i\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)^k, \quad t\in[-1,1].
$$

(Version 2)
$$H_k(t):=\cos(k\arccos(t)),\quad t\in[-1,1].$$

Is there any reference to say that these two versions are equivalent? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $t\in[-1,1]$, put $t = \cos \theta$ with $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi$.  Then $\sin\theta \geqslant 0$ and $\theta =\cos^{-1}t$.  Now substituting in the first formula, you obtain
\begin{align}
H_k(t) &= \frac{1}{2} e^{ik \theta} + \frac{1}{2} e^{-ik\theta} \\
&= \cos k\theta
\end{align}
so the two are equivalent.